# Checkstyle Magic numbers in ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, checkstyle

Is this possible, to suppress checkstyle "Magic number" errors when I try to get specific column from a result set?

To be clear, I have code like this

```
resultSet.getBigDecimal(1)
```

or

```
resultSet.getString(1)
```

where digit - is the column index in the result set. Can I avoid suppression for that case (not with annotations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ResultSet API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/ResultSet.html) offers getters that work with column names, such as [getString(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString-java.lang.String-). Then your code would look like this:

```
resultSet.getBigDecimal("EmployeeID")
resultSet.getString("EmployeeName");
```

This resolves the magic number problem, and gives a good clue about what it is that you are reading from the table.

From a Checkstyle point of view, suppression would not be conveniently possible, as you would have to annotate every single case.

Comment: So, as I understand, we can't add some settings in xml config file, only use supression annotations or refactor code?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately so. (Not counting esoteric solutions such as defining XPath expressions for these cases or something.) But I believe that using the column names is actually quite a nice solution. :-)